# Change default GET operation used by API platform for GetCollection items

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a custom Get operation on the user entity "/users/me" which is my first operation. Hence, it matches sooner than the "/users/{id}" operation used to retrieve a specific user.

But now, every user in GetCollection "/users" have {"@id": "/users/me"}

If I swap the order of the "/users/me" with "/users/{id}" then the "/users" works fine, but then for "/users/me" I get a not found exception because a user with id "me" does not exist, obviously.

> **By default**, API Platform uses the first Get operation defined to generate the IRI of an item and the first GetCollection operation to generate the IRI of a collection.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/

Is there any way to override the default behavior for a certain collection operation?

I have tried naming my routes and tried to figure out a way from Get operation class attributes which attribute can override the "first operation **by default**" but I have failed to find it in the documentation or in the code.

Do I have any other option to keep "/users/me" or do I have to forget about using "/users/me" as an endpoint and rather use something else?

Thank you

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/users/me',
            controller: UserBasicInfo::class,
            description: 'Get the current user basic information.',
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['user:me:get'],
            ],
            security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
            securityMessage: 'Access denied.',
            read: false,
            write: false,
            name: "api_users_get_self",
        ),
        new Get(

            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['user:get'],
            ],
            security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
            securityMessage: 'Access denied.',
            read: true,
            name: "api_users_get_item",
        ),
        new GetCollection(
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['user:get:collection'],
            ],
            security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
            securityMessage: 'Access denied.',
        ),
        ...
    ],
    paginationEnabled: true,
)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution posted by @Aymeric works fine however it has some drawbacks on the documentation generation side.

I was experimenting and came across an idea, that if I use the `/users/{id}` operation first so it works as default, but add the uriTemplate explicitly and set the requirement for {id} to be a digit, then the `/users/{id}` should not match for the `/users/me` and it should continue for the custom `/users/me` operation.

- Responses for Collection and Get are correct
- Response for `/users/me` is correct
- Auto-generated documentation is correct

```
new Get(
    uriTemplate: '/users/{id}',
    requirements: ['id' => '\d+'],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['user:get'],
    ],
),
new Get(
    uriTemplate: '/users/me',
    controller: UserBasicInfo::class,
    description: 'Get the current user basic information.',
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['user:me:get'],
    ],
),
new GetCollection(
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['user:get:collection'],
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Get operation of the '/users/me' endpoint by a GetCollection :

```php
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/users/me',
            controller: UserBasicInfo::class,
            description: 'Get the current user basic information.',
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['user:me:get'],
            ],
            security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
            securityMessage: 'Access denied.',
            read: false,
            write: false,
            name: "api_users_get_self",
        ),
        ...
    ],
    paginationEnabled: true,
)]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have found a possibly better solution by accident

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#defining-which-operation-to-use-to-generate-the-iri) correctly, this option in your `GetCollection` is exactly for your scenario:

```
itemUriTemplate: '/users/{id}'
```